# GoogleEarth crashed or still loading?

Tags: kml, google-earth

How do you know if the (free) GoogleEarth App is still loading data or hasnt crashed for some reaons.

Im loading a huge kml file, 100% cpu usage, but it never stops processing..

Are there any limits about the KML size of the displayed file?

How many KML MBs the Google Earth PC application can show without crashing ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any file size limitations for Google Earth when using .kml files. There is however limits with regard to the size of images, so if your kml is trying to load images (such as screen overlays) then perhaps your problem lies there.
This is related to the specifications of your computer, so you can find the maximum resolution of images you can import by looking under the 'About'. I am not sure where to find info about the kb size of the image.

Next, you can try creating a .kmz out of the .kml - A KMZ is simply a compressed file the same as a .zip is - learn more about it
http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmzarchives.html

Also you can try breaking the file up into smaller ones, either by using network links
http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#networklink

or Regions
http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/regions.html

By breaking the file up into smaller ones, you might also discover which part/element of the KML is causing hassles if you have some kind of format error